# redirecting process output on richtext box in c#

Tags: c#

I want to redirect output of process on richtext box in c# from application.
But the problem is output of process is displyed after a long time till process finishes its work.

here is my code-

```
        StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = strHMIModelAppFolder;
        processStartInfo.FileName = ConfigurationHandlerInstance.GetHMIModelApplication();

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler
        (
            delegate(object objSender, DataReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                outputBuilder.Append(eventArgs.Data);
                outputBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                this.SetText(outputBuilder.ToString());
            }
        );

        process.Exited += new EventHandler(ProcExited);
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        //process.WaitForExit();
        //while (!process.HasExited)
        //{
        //    Application.DoEvents();
        //}

        // use the output
        string output = outputBuilder.ToString();
        this.SetText(output);
```

Comment: How should I show process output in realtime?

Comment: Is there a buffer flush issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read in the output while it is generated, like this:

```
proc.Start();
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    outputBuilder.Append(line);
    outputBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    this.SetText(outputBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I Tried this solution but still data is not displayed in real time.